# How to get a related record item from a different table

Tags: php, codeigniter

Firstly I have no idea about Codeigniter, though I am OK'ish with general PHP/MYSQL

I am trying to get an additional field [unlock_code] content from a related record. I have a Sales table and a product table

Here is the Error I get when I try it....

> ```
> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Notice
> Message: Undefined variable: unlock_code
> Filename: controllers/Paypal.php
> ```

---

```
 // Load libraries
    $this->load->library('AppSettings');
    //  Load models
    $this->load->model('m_customers');
    $this->load->model('m_products');

    // Get customer and product data
    $customer  = $this->m_customers->by_cid($sale['cid']);
    $product  = $this->m_products->get_product($sale['pid']);

    $configs = array(
        'protocol'  => $this->appsettings->get('email_method'),
        'smtp_host' => $this->appsettings->get('smtp_host'),
        'smtp_user' => $this->appsettings->get('smtp_username'),
        'smtp_pass' => $this->appsettings->get('smtp_password'),
        'smtp_port' => $this->appsettings->get('smtp_port'),
        'smtp_crypto' => $this->appsettings->get('smtp_crypto'),
    );



    $this->load->library("email", $configs);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->to($customer['cust_email']);
    $this->email->from(
        $this->appsettings->get('support_email'), 
        $this->appsettings->get('support_contact_person')
    );

    $search = array(
        '%CUSTOMER NAME%',
        '%CUSTOMER EMAIL%',
        '%PRODUCT NAME%',
        '%PRODUCT PRICE%',
        '%DOWNLOAD LINK%',
        '%DOWNLOAD EXPIRY%',
        '%UNLOCK CODE%',

    );

    $replace = array(
        $customer['cust_firstname'].' '.$customer['cust_lastname'],
        $customer['cust_email'],
        $product['name'],
        $product['price'],
        site_url('download/'.$sale['download_code']),
        $product['expiry'],
        $product['unlock_code'],
    );
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you `var_dump($product->result())`, is unlock_code output?

Comment: I'll try that thank you

Comment: No joy I'm affraid

Comment: Can you post your code for this function? `$this->m_products->get_product()`

Comment: function get_product($pid) {
        $res = $this->db->get_where($this->table, array('pid' => $pid), 1);
        if ($res->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $res->first_row('array');
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: From what I understand, the function gets a **row** where the pid of the product matches the pid of the sales. For some reason the "unlock_code" field is not being included.

Could writing a new function, "get_unlock_code" where pid matches the sales pid and fetch it singularly work? I have no idea how to do that but just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The query was not fetching the unlock code field from the products database for some reason. So i changed it from...

```
function get_product($pid) {
    $res = $this->db->get_where($this->table, array('pid' => $pid), 1);
    if ($res->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $res->first_row('array');
    }
    return false;
}
```

To

```
function get_product($pid) {
    $res = $this->db->select('*')->get_where($this->table, array('pid' => $pid), 1);
    if ($res->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $res->first_row('array');
    }
    return false;
}
```

That sorted it.

Thank you for the offers of help